# Google map road distance calculation inside mysql query

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, google-maps

I am developing a website for car sales using php .I am using code igniter framework.
There is a serach page with an option for finding nearest cars.
I used the following query for fetching the car list

```
  $given_distance=100;

  $q = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  GROUP_CONCAT(img_name) AS images, cars.id,cars.user,cars.status,cars.engine_size,cars.price_max,cars.title,cars.distance as distance_covered,date_format(cars.date_posted,'%d-%M') as date_posted,body.body,fuel.fuel,make.make as make,company.company,model.model,users.firstname,users.role,users.phone,users.lastname,users.latitude as map_latitude,users.longitude as map_longitude,users.city as map_city,user_payment.status as payment_status,color.color as color,color.code as color_code,transmission.transmission ";

  if($longitude&&$latitude&&$distance&&$postcode!=''){$q.=" , CAST(3959 * 2 *     ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN(({$latitude} - `latitude`) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) + COS({$latitude} * pi()/180) * COS(`latitude` * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(({$longitude} - `longitude`) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as DECIMAL(10, 2))*1.5 AS distance ";}else{$q.=',0 as distance '; }
 $q.=" from cars left join users on cars.user=users.id left join make on cars.make=make.id  where cars.status=1 having distance<=$given_distance";
```

The query is working fine and i am getting then result. But the problem is the query calculates straight line distance but i need the driving distance like in google map

i find a code for finding driving distance like follows

```
/*
 * function for calculating distance between two places
 * @parm $from,$to
 * @return 
 */
public function find_distance($from=688538,$to=682018)
{   
    $start = $from; 
    $destination = $to;
    $mode = "driving";  
    $xml = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=$start&destinations=$destination&mode=$mode&language=en-EN&sensor=false");
    $data = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    $distance = $data->row->element->distance->text;
    $time = $data->row->element->duration->text;
    if(empty($distance) OR empty($time)){
    return $to;
        //echo 'reverr';die();
    }else{
    return floatval($distance);die();
    }
}//find distance
```

now the problem is  how i use this function inside the mysql query

Comment: how are you expecting to use the function in a query? You will have to return the lats / longs and then call the google api with each of the start - end points.

Comment: the query needs the result of the function as distance inside the query, and the function needs a value from the query result like a postcode

Comment: but why are you still using that function? Just query the lats / longs and use google API to get distances - your code is now null and void if you want driving distance instead! You CANNOT use a result from another website inside your query - if you desperately need to do this you will have to query once for lat & long and then once more inputting lat, long and distance that was returned from google.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT `place1`, `place2` FROM table WHERE id = 'something';
$query = $ci->db->query($sql);

$arr = array();

foreach ($query->result() as $row){

    $arr[] = find_distance($from=$row['place1'],$to=$row['place2']);

}

print_r($arr);
```

The above should give you what you need (when you plug in the correct field names that is!)

Comment: This is ok .But the problem is at the end of the query I am using a having that needs the calculated distance 
     having distance<=$given_distance

Comment: yes - that is done in CI not in your query -> the array gives you all the info you need. Why not query to get straight line distance of say 8 miles (for a 10 mile distance) and then use google API to filter out the ones that are over 10 miles while driving - this will be your simplest solution without too many calls to the API.